# Trade-offs between explicit or implicit account id in a REST route

Tags: rest, url

Please consider the following example (common in SaaS applications):

This is a SaaS that deals with Widgets.

- You have an Account, that you authenticate via an API key. Each API key authenticates only one Account.
- You have several Widgets under your Account. A Widget belongs to only one Account and can't be transferred to other Accounts.

The URL representation of a widget can be:

1. `https://api.domain.com/v0/accounts/{accountId}/widgets/{widgetId}`
2. `https://api.domain.com/v0/widgets/{widgetId}`

The difference is that route 1 makes has the accountId explicit and route 2 has it implicit (in the authentication via the API key).

### Examples

In the wild there seems to be examples for both alternatives:

For example, **[Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice)** makes the accountId explicit. To make an outbound call:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json \
--data-urlencode "Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" \
--data-urlencode "From=+15010000000" \
--data-urlencode "To=+12300000000" \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

and **[Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api)** has the accountId implicit. For example, to retrive your balance:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2:
```

**What are the trade-offs to both alternatives (explicit and implicit)?**

Answer (score 1):

One advantage I can see in using case 1 (`https://api.domain.com/v0/accounts/{accountId}/widgets/{widgetId}`) is that the URL corresponds to a particular resource, whereas this is not true in case 2. The case 1 URL specifies a particular widget via its `widgetId` and the account with id `accountId` that it is associated with. In contrast it is not possible to determine the particular widget from the case 2 URL since it does not include the account id. From this argument case 1 is more 'RESTful'.

A similar question that discusses some further tradeoffs is here:

[REST API design: POST (implicit userId) vs PUT (explicit userId)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284452/rest-api-design-post-implicit-userid-vs-put-explicit-userid)

Comment: Thank you. If we asume that widgetId is unique (for example a GUID) then both would be equivalent in functionality?

Comment: If the widgetId was globally unique then yes, I'd definitely agree